# How to get values of my fields through hyperlink in action?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want get values of my hidden fields to my action.
When I click on a hyperlink the request will be send to an action but in my action i am unable to get values of my hidden fields .

My JSP is like :

```
<s:form action="getValues" method="post" theme="simple" name="getvaluesForm" id="getvaluesForm">
    <s:hidden name="hidden1" value="First Hidden Field" />
    <s:hidden name="hidden2" value="Second Hidden Field" />
    <s:hidden name="hidden3" value="Third Hidden Field" />
    <s:a action="getValues"  name="anchorTag">Submit Using Action Attribute</s:a><br />
    <s:a onclick="document.forms['getvaluesForm'].submit();" href="#" name="">Submit Using Onclick Event</s:a>
</s:form>
```

My action is like :

```
private String hidden1;
private String hidden2;
private String hidden3;
private String anchorTag;
...
...
getters ans setters

 public GetValuesAction()
{
    System.out.println("Entered To Constructor");
    System.out.println("First Field : "+hidden1);
    System.out.println("Second Field : "+hidden2);
    System.out.println("Third Field : "+hidden3);
    System.out.println("Anchor Tag : "+anchorTag);
}

public String execute()
{
    return "success";
}
```

I got values of my hidden fields as `null`

How to get values of my hidden fields in my action?

I hope I have provided all the required info. If I missed out please point out.

Comment: Can you see whether the hidden fields are being transmitted? Use developer tools in your browser (F12) to inspect the request and confirm.

Comment: I did not find hidden fields being transfered , I opened browser executed my code and pressed F12 but i did not find anything . 'null' was returned to my action when i click on the links .

Comment: Could you try using a regular `<input type="Submit"/>` instead of the anchor and Javascript? If that works, then you'll know it's a problem with the Javascript.

Comment: I removed those anchor tags and i added `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` but still `null` was returned

Comment: `Will Keeling` I found answer to it . At first i have placed `System.out.println` statements inside constructor . Now i kept `System.out.println` statements inside execute method . Now my action is able to get values of hidden fields . No modifications inside Jsp .

Comment: post your form please

Comment: `<s:form action="getValues" method="post" theme="simple" name="getvaluesForm" id="getvaluesForm">`    `<s:hidden type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="First Hidden Field" />`    `<s:hidden name="hidden2" value="Second Hidden Field" />`    `<s:a onclick="document.forms['getvaluesForm'].submit();" href="#" name="anchorTag" value="Submit">Submit</s:a>`

Comment: I am unable to post answer to this question So i posted code as comment .